# The meaning of symbols " £ ", " ³ ", " i " and " Û "?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning Linear Algebra right now and I am seeing some new symbols. These are from my schools online document. I can write the exact examples they're used at:

```
In the natural number set we can also define the ³ relation:

n ³ m (we say that m is greater or equal than n) when m < n or m = n.

Theorem:

The relation ³ has the following properties:

    n ³ n,
    (m £ n and m ³ n ) Þ (m = n),
    (m ³ n and n ³ k) Þ (m ³ k),
    For every pair n, m either m £ n or m ³ n,
    n ³ 0.
```

And for the i and Û symbol,

```
Definition

Complex numbers are ordered pairs of two real numbers e.g. (a, b), (c, d), with equality, addition and multiplication defined as follows:
( a, b ) = ( c, d ) Û a = c i b = d
```

So for the "³" symbol, I understand the meaning but because that I couldn't find any document that uses this in any website, I got curious if it's a right symbol or not. And for the others, I just couldn't really get them.

Thanks!

Comment: its most likely some character mishap. ³ is $\geq$, £ is $\leq$, and so on

Comment: Then I would love to learn what each of those false symbols means in reality if we're sure that they're wrong.
³ is ≥, £ is ≤, and i, Û?

Comment: This is certainly a rendering issue.

Answer (score 7):

You are a victim of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

The characters you're seeing are from the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character encoding, in which:

- `£` = 0xA3
- `³` = 0xB3
- `Û` = 0xDB
- `Þ` = 0xDE

But it appears that the author's intention was to render the characters [in the Symbol font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)), in which:

- 0xA3 = `≤`
- 0xB3 = `≥`
- 0xDB = `⇔`
- 0xDE = `⇒`

So, just search and replace these character codes, to get:

```
In the natural number set we can also define the ≥ relation:

n ≥ m (we say that m is greater or equal than n) when m < n or m = n.

Theorem:

The relation ≥ has the following properties:

    n ≥ n,
    (m ≤ n and m ≥ n ) ⇒ (m = n),
    (m ≥ n and n ≥ k) ⇒ (m ≥ k),
    For every pair n, m either m ≤ n or m ≥ n,
    n ≥ 0.

Definition

Complex numbers are ordered pairs of two real numbers e.g. (a, b), (c, d), with equality, addition and multiplication defined as follows:
( a, b ) = ( c, d ) ⇔ a = c ∧ b = d
```

The odd character out is `i`, which is encoded as 0x69, corresponding to Symbol character `ι` (Greek small letter iota).  This doesn't make sense in context, but Symbol character 0xD9 = `∧` (Logical AND) does.  Somehow, a few bits got mangled in transit.  I've manually made this correction above.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to set my encoding settings to those somehow? Or should I just talk about it with my school? I really need a solution because it's just the start of the school and there'll probably be more mistaken characters in the future documents.

Comment: @Daffy: You could open the document in Microsoft Word (or similar word processing software), highlight the wrong symbols, and change the font to “Symbol”.  (Or even change the font for the whole document ιφ ψου χαν ρεαδ φαυξ Γρεεκ λικε τηισ.)  But ask your instructor to see if you can get a corrected version of the document.

Comment: I don't think it would be practical nor easy to highlight all the wrong symbols all the time for the whole semester, so I've asked about an updated document. Thank you again for the help.